# Set the height of a DIV to be divisible by 'n', rounding up. Recalculate on window resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a website to build that features illustrated repeating borders. The border illustration is 232px high, and I need to ensure my content area is always divisible by this number in order to avoid clipping the border (always rounding up).

I have part of the solution thanks to a similar question asked a couple of years ago but it doesn't recalculate height when the browser window is re-sized; important this era of responsive web:

```
    $(function(){
    var curHeight = parseInt($("#content_area").height()),
        newHeight = Math.ceil(curHeight/232) * 232;
    $("#content_area").height(newHeight );
    });
```

Can anyone help out?

Comment: You need to keep your container at same height irrespective of window's height?

Comment: No, the content will increase or reduce in height as the browser window width is reduced / increased. I need the container to increase / decrease in height, in multiples of 232. See here for an example change the width of the browser window to see the border break):[link]http://fenrisgames.cloudlevel.me/

Comment: Then don't you think that container's height should be proportional to window's height and then your magic number 232.

Comment: Not sure I follow your thinking. As far as I see it, the window height has no bearing on container height - it's the window width that determines the height of the content, and thus the container.

Comment: Ok, got it. updated my answer this should work now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following solves this issue:

```
$('document').ready(function() {
var heightAdj = (function() {
    $('.auto-height').css('height', 'auto');
    var curHeight = parseInt($(".auto-height").height());
    var newHeight = Math.ceil(curHeight/232) * 232;
    $(".auto-height").height(newHeight);
}); 
$(window).resize(heightAdj);

$(window).trigger('resize');
```

});

Answer (score 1):

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    var curHeight = parseInt($("#content_area").height()),
    newHeight = Math.ceil(curHeight/232) * 232;
    $("#content_area").height(newHeight );
});
```

Comment: Thank you, but this does not seem to work on page load, or browser re-size.

Answer (score 0):

try `.resize()`:

```
    $(function(){
      $(window).on('resize', function(){
          var curHeight = parseInt($("#content_area").height()),
              newHeight = Math.ceil(curHeight/232) * 232;
         $("#content_area").height(newHeight );
      }).resize(); // <---calculates on dom ready
    });
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This works on browser load, but not on re-size.

Answer (score 0):

as far as my understanding goes I think you shouldn't use

```
$(window).resize()
```

You should rather use

```
$(window).on('resize', function(){
    // Alien Arrays Code
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/on/

Steve

Answer (score 0):

use **[resize()](http://api.jquery.com/resize/)** and **[trigger()](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)**

```
$(function(){

  /** first bind event on resize */   
   $(window).on('resize', function(){
          var curHeight = parseInt($("#content_area").height()),
              newHeight = Math.ceil(curHeight/232) * 232;
         $("#content_area").height(newHeight );
      });
 /* then trigger on document load */
   $(window).resize(); 
   //or
   $(window).trigger("resize"); 
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function doResize() {

    var curHeight = parseInt($("#content_area").height()),
        newHeight = Math.ceil(curHeight / 232) * 232;

    $("#content_area").height(newHeight);
}
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    doResize();
});
window.onresize = doResize;
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried this but it still doesn't recalculate the container height on window re-size. I setup a test page and stripped everything else out: [link]http://cloudlevel.me/test. On initial load, everything is great. If I then reduce browser width, the content increases in width until it's outside the bounds of the container.

Comment: I figured out what is missing in your page. Just add `overflow:auto;` to your `content_area` style.

Comment: Sorry, you misunderstand. I need the containing DIV to re-size with the content (in increments of 232px). Thanks for your help thus far!

Comment: Then I will again say this is not possible with your logic. I mean you can fix height of your container but not the content size with this code. And with decrease in window's size the size of your container will also decrease and multiplying this with a constant value will not help you.

Comment: So you need to define your logic against window's width and height both.